# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having an array of dictionaries in TypeScript which is something like this:

```
const dict = [
     { name: "Lorem", prop: "sit" },
     { name: "Ipsum", prop: "amet" },
     { name: "Dolor", prop: "consectetur" }
];
```

When I try to access the objects from this dictionary dynamically by:

```
const handleChange = React.useCallback((eventKey: eventKey) => {
    let property = dict.find(e => e.name === eventKey)?.prop;
    changeProp(property);  //Getting error here
}
```

Please note that this is dynamic changes and the demo can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/mdhjfq13/3/

The error that I am getting is:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I have tried using it like this:

```
let property = dict.find(e => e.name === eventKey);
let name1:string = property.prop!; //Error here
changeProp(name1);
```

Error now obtained is: `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

I do not know how to deal with this as I am new to TypeScript and React.

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen when no matching object is found?

Comment: Maybe return a default search like the first object with name "Lorem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns the first **element** from the array that satisfies the condition. But it returns `undefined` when no matching element was found.

That makes return type of `find` to be `Your_Element_Type | undefined` i.e. `string | undefined` for your question (*after reading `prop` on the result of `find`*).

#### Issue

```js
let property = dict.find((e) => e.name === eventKey)?.prop
// property will either be a string or undefined
changeProp(property);
```

To fix this, you either need to accept `string | undefined` in the function `changeProp`, or provide a fallback string value (empty string).

#### Solution

Providing an empty string as fallback value:

```
let property = dict.find((e) => e.name === eventKey)?.prop ?? ''
changeProp(property);
```

Also, type can be seen in an editor:
[image: string]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, by this, it is always taking null value as default

Comment: My bad, sorry. It was a silly mistake from my side. But thanks though. this helped me.

Answer (score 2):

```
const handleChange = React.useCallback((eventKey: eventKey) => {
    let property = dict.find(e => e.name === eventKey)?.prop;
    changeProp(property);  //Getting error here
}
```

Here, in your function, when you find on dict, you are supposing that the find function could return an empty value `dict.find(e => e.name === eventKey)?.prop`,
in this way `property` could be `undefined | string`.

Try updating your function in this way `dict.find(e => e.name === eventKey)?.prop || ""`, this means that if the find does not return any value, instead of undefined, the variable `property` will be `""`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, by this, it is always taking null value as default.